# c - redis - trying to understand bitset intersection

Tags: c, indexing, redis, bit-manipulation, intersection

Given two bitsets of say 100000 elements.

Would AND'ing those two bitsets (on my Debian 64-bit machine)
result in AND'ing 32 bits at a time, i.e. total iterations required: 3125 (100000 /32)?

Isn't there anything faster to find the intersection between two sets? That would definitely help if the arrays become much bigger.

Comment: As you say you use a 64 bits system, you could try to AND 64 bits per 64 bits (half the number of operations) ... But I cannot imagine a better way without special dedicated hardware ...

Comment: Debian uses at most 47 bits if I recall correctly so the gap is not that interesting (but still :))

Comment: Assuming this is x86, there's a 128-bit AND instruction in SSE2 (available on all AMD64 and EMT64 supporting processors). The bitness of the OS is irrelevant.

Comment: Yes you are right about the OS. +1